# Extjs combo setbind not working

Tags: extjs

I'm using the following code in order to set the selected value:
 `this.myCombo.setBind('{rec.my_value}');` 
All my data is in "rec".
Options for choose are being filled in the combo as expected but no value is set to the selected value.
Why is this happening and how to solve?
Tried already put the above bind after data is being loaded and after page is already rendered, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code something like this:

```
{
    xtype:'combo',
    store:'mystore',
    valueField:'id', // you will get this value by default after selection
    displayField:'name', // it will responsible to show display as option on combo  
    listeners: {
        change : function(cmp){
            var value = cmp.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `id` and `name` are the record data of store. Now, whenever you select any option, then it will display.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be `listerners`?  Or have you posted this without even testing it?